# Determine all positive rational numbers $r \neq 1$ such that $r^{\frac{1}{r-1}}$ is rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, rational-numbers

Here's what I've got so far:

Let $r = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. We then have $$r^{\frac{1}{r-1}} = \frac{a^{\frac{b}{a-b}}}{b^{\frac{b}{a-b}}}$$

Clearly, $a-b=1$ and $a-b=-1$ work. But it might be the case that $a-b \neq 1$ or $a-b \neq -1$, but $\frac{a^{\frac{b}{a-b}}}{b^{\frac{b}{a-b}}}$ still be rational, if it turns out that $a=p^{\frac{1}{a-b}}$ and $b=q^{\frac{1}{a-b}}$.

But how do I obtain a contradiction if $a-b > 1$, or $a-b<-1$? I let $a-b=n$, which means that $a=p^{n}$ and $b=q^{n}$, so $$a-b = p^n - q^n = n$$

This is strangely curious, because it's worked out well so far. I can see that the expression in the middle can be factored, but how will that help with the contradiction?

If you have your own way of approaching this problem, feel free to comment. Thanks.

Comment: How do you obtain a contradiction if $a-b\lt -1$? Something like $a=3, b=7$ satisfies that condition (the result isn't rational, but that doesn't necessarily immediately follow).

Comment: True, I'll edit my post. That means I'm still stuck at obtaining a contradiction if $a-b <-1$ or $a-b>1$

Comment: I have not looked enough, but certainly $p^n-q^n$ is not possible if $n\ge 2$, for already by the binomial theorem $(q+1)^n-q^n\ge nq^{n-1}+1

Comment: @AndréNicolas, mind elaborating on using the Binomial Theorem for a contradiction?

Comment: For it to be rational then $a = \alpha^{a - b}$ and $b = \beta^{a - b}$ so we really just need to choose a difference: $\gamma = a - b$ and then show: $a = \alpha^\gamma$, $b = \beta^\gamma$, therefore $a - b = \gamma$ which leads to $\gamma =\alpha^\gamma - \beta^\gamma$...I have no idea if that helps or not or if it's just restating the problem...which it probably is (obviously $\gamma$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ have to be integers here).

Comment: It is the same remark as the one by Thomas Andrews. Let $n\ge 2$. Then $(q+1)^n=q^{n}+\binom{n}{1}q^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}q+1$ (there may only be three terms if $n=2$). The sum of the last two terms is $nq+1\gt n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But $q+1$ and $q$ differ by 1, whereas I did not stipulate how much $c$ and $d$ must differ? Plus the expansion of $(q+1)^{n}$ is not the same as $c^{n-1} + c^{n-2}d + ... +  cd^{n-2} + d^{n-1}$.

Comment: If they differ by more than $1$, then $p^n\gt (q+1)^n \ge q^n+ nq+1\gt q^n+n$. So $p^n-q^n\gt n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to start with $\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{a}{b}$ so $r=\frac{a-b}{a}$. then you want $a-b$ and $a$ to be perfect $b$th power, or $b-a$ and $-a$ to be perfect $b$th powers. But $\left|(k+1)^b-k^b\right|$ is greater than $b$ when $b>1$ and $k\neq -1,0$, and the $k=-1,0$ cases are no good when $b>1$. So if $b>1$ then there are no solutions.

The case when $b=1$, however, gives a solution for any $a\neq 0$.

Comment: What is the motivation behind $\frac{1}{1-r} = \frac{a}{b}$? Also, what is the motivation behind $k$ and $k+1$, where they both differ by $1$? I apologise if my question is overly trivial.

Comment: Motivation was I saw it and tried it and it worked. What do you mean "motivation?" I've needed motivation on stage occasionally, to explain why my character is angry or laughing or exiting. If two perfect $b$th powers differ by $b$, then two consecutive perfect $b$th powers must differ by at most $b$. So we look at consecutive $b$th powers first.

Comment: Your last line was what I needed. I get it now, thank you very much --- it seems I need to work more to be able to see these things.